# Hidden counter?

Tags: c

In order to count occurrences, for example, with F# I could do:

```
let l = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5];
let rec f (l: int list) (n: int) :int =
    match l, n with
    | [], _                     -> 0
    | [x], n                    -> 1
    | x::xs when x <> n         -> f(xs, n)
    | x::xs when x = n          -> 1 + f(xs, n)
```

With C,I usually use a counter, that store the result each time it is incremented, conceptually similar to:

```
i += 1 + f(xs, n);
return i;
```

Please consider this problem, where we have an infinite number of blue and red marbles. The function should compute the number
of sequences of n marbles such that it never happens that three marbles with the same colours are consecutive.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int count(int k, char last, char prev);
int up_count(int n);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
        int n;
        printf("\n\nNumber of marbles:\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("\n\nSequences: %d\n\n", up_count(n));
        return 0;
}



int count(int k, char last, char prev){
        if(k == 0)
                return 1;
        else{
                if(last == prev)
                        return (last == 'R') ? count(k - 1, 'B', last) : count(k - 1, 'R', last);
                else
                        return count(k - 1, 'R', last) + count(k - 1, 'B', last);
        }       
}       

int up_count(int k){
        return count(k, 'x', 'y');
}
```

Where do `up_count` and `count` store the increasing amount of sequences? According to my brief experience, without an accumulator, the function should just return `1` when it comes to the base case.

Comment: Look at the generated code. My guess is that temporary values are stored on the CPU stack, while the return values are returned in a CPU register (that then might be pushed onto the stack).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that is an interesting case. I am going to collect some intel on this. I hope it goes not beyond my actual skills.

Comment: The C language does not make any requirements how/where these are stored or the compiler does not convert this to iterative machine code. On the same architecture, they most likely use the same facilities as functional PLs. Note that on a machine with **finite** storage, there cannot be an **in**finite number of bits stored. Anyway, we are not a tutoring site. These basics will be explained by general computing/CS books and more detailed books about programming and compiler construction. You question is in fact not bound to a specific programming language (and definitively not about F#).

Comment: I dont know if I get your problem but it seems to me this should be solveable with some `fold`ing, no?
https://fpish.net/blog/anton.tayanovskyy/id/1453/http~3a~2f~2fwww.intellifactory.com~2fblogs~2fanton.tayanovskyy~2f2009~2f12~2f11~2fFoldr-or-FoldBack-on-Infinite-F~21sharp~21-Sequences.article

Comment: @Olaf, you are right, the F# code here is just an example to, hopefully, help me to communicate the problem to the community. Apparently, I just get the nose in an issue that goes beyond my actual competences. In any case, thank you a lot for the details you provided me.

Comment: Recursive functions store internal state on the stack. Which causes potential stack overflow, so it is a bad practise.

Comment: @Worice: As long as you accept it at the moment and take learning it as a challenge, all is fine. Too bad most people today feel personally offended being told they need to learn more to understand something. So heads up,  you have a good attitude.

Comment: @Simon: 1) There is no stack in the C language. 2) Wether this will result in recursive machine code, too depends on the actual problem and the toolchain. Modern compilers try to avoid recursive code, because it has a lot of negative implications, e.g. for memory available. But that is all implementation specific.

Comment: @Olaf No stack in C ? No call stack ? You mean virtually the C compiler can manage that with no allocation ... but in reality your gcc will stack overflow.

Comment: @Simon What Olaf means is that the C standard don't define anything about a stack.

Comment: @Simon: 1) gcc is not the only compiler. 2) x86 is not the only architecture, not even the most sold single architecture 3) You confuse implementation and standard. Please read about the differences. 4) There are architectures which don't **necessarily** use a stack **for the variables**. See PIC, good HC08 compilers (option) 5) The compiler micht choose to inline all functions -> no stack at all. 6) As I wrote, even on x86 the compiler might convert certain recursive functions to interative machine code (simplest case: tail-recursion).

Comment: 1) but one of the most pro eminent 2) The processor architecture is irrelevant here, it's compiler design. And ARM doesn't change anything here 3) You sure love standards 4) idem 2). 5) How do inline recursive code ? infinite code ? 6) it might, for simple cases. In general it won't. Tail call elimination isn't part of the C standard.